# jQuery/javascript :Overriding getElementsAtPosition(x,y) for a getting elements of area instead of a specific position

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom

I'm looking for same method like `getElementsAtPosition(x,y)` but instead of position I want to get all DOM for a given area (may be a rectangle). So it should look something like  `getAllElementsAtArea(x,y,width,height)`. 
what I tried is http://jsfiddle.net/mantrig/3tqqy0gt/

Answer (score 0):

Although  you don't have a native method for this, there are many ways you can do it. It is possible to build an algorithm which uses `getElementsAtPosition(x,y)` to search an area. Or you can get all elements and see if they fall inside a specific area.

Please see [this](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/4002059/get-dom-elements-inside-a-rectangle-area-of-a-page) question.

Comment: Thanks !! This seems to be a possible solution, but I'm afraid about the performance  there  are two scenarios first, I don't have a specific element to search like they did for `<li>` I want all elements  & second I have thousands of DOM elements in my screen (its a svg) so traversing through all elements will be a serious concern specially on low-end PC (performance wise).

Comment: The selected answer in that question is not suitable if you have a lot of DOM elements and you cannot specify a selector. Your best bet then should be to develop an algorithm which can get the elements in an area. This can be done by betting getElementAtPosition to scan through many points which comprises an area. You can exclude the sub-areas from this scan as you find elements to optimize the algorithm. I will write one this evening if I get extra time.

Comment: Hmm this could be a best way as of now. Will try it!! For this I need to reduce size of my rect so that I can get result faster but still I feel there is some other mechanism to achieve this with better performance (may be). Like they do for image-zoom plug-in it is quite same.

Comment: I'm sure the latter algorithm I proposed would work in a split of a second even for an area which is 500x 500. I will do it and update my answer.

Comment: Tried using getElementsAtPosition along with mouseover, my browser died lolzz not sure how our rectangular select with work with it :P

Comment: I'm not surprised to hear that your browser died when you call such an expensive method in a busy even like mouseOver. It's like making an elephant sit on a speeding merry-go-round! :0

Answer (score 0):

hope i understood you correctly.

```js
//this function gives back the top, left, width and height of chosen html element in body
function count_elements(i, index) {


var count = document.body.childNodes;

 var i;
 var w = count[i].clientWidth;
 var h = count[i].clientHeight;
 var y = count[i].offsetTop;
 var x = count[i].offsetLeft;
 
 //this returns width OR height OR top OR left of concrete element [i]
 if (index == 'w') {
  return w;
 } else if (index == 'h') {
  return h;
 } else if (index == 'x') {
  return x;
 } else if (index == 'y') {
  return y;
 }
 
}

//this function is checking whether html element is in the area
function move_area(event) {

 var area = document.getElementById('area');

 //check the mouse X and Y position while mouse move
 var mouse_y = event.clientY;
 var mouse_x = event.clientX;

 //check the area properties
 var area_w = area.clientWidth;
 var area_h = area.clientHeight;
 var area_y = area.offsetTop;
 var area_x = area.offsetLeft;


  //move the area depending on mouse X and Y position
  area.style.top = mouse_y - area_h/2 + "px";
  area.style.left = mouse_x - area_w/2 + "px";
        area.style.visibility = "visible";

 //check html elements in BODY
 var count = document.body.childNodes;

  //i=2 because first element in body is AREA - you shoud avoid this element in LOOP
  for (i=2; i<count.length-1; i++) {

   //check properties of all HTML elements using above function - count_elements
   var box_w = count_elements(i, 'w');
   var box_h = count_elements(i, 'h');
   var box_y = count_elements(i, 'y');
   var box_x = count_elements(i, 'x');


   //avoid HTML elements without width, height, top and left properties - #text in code outside html tags
   if (box_w != undefined && box_h != undefined && box_y != undefined && box_x != undefined) {
    //check if HTML element is INSIDE area
    if (area_y < box_y && area_x < box_x && (area_y+area_h) > (box_y+box_h) && (area_x+area_w) > (box_x+box_w)) {
      //change BORDER of element which is INSIDE area
      count[i].style.border = "dotted 4px #FF55AA";
     } else {
      //release BORDER of element which is OUTSIDE area
      count[i].style.borderStyle = "none";
      }
   } 
  }
}
```

```css
body {
 width:100vw;
 height:100vw;
}

#area {
 width: 500px;
 height:300px;
 border: dotted 1px #000000;
 position:fixed;
    visibility:hidden;
}


.div_samp1 {
 width:200px;
 height: 100px;
 position: absolute;
 top:56px;
 left:26px;
 background-color:#CAF0FC;
 color:#33AAFF;"
}

.p_samp1 {
 position: absolute;
 top:156px;
 left:256px;
 background-color:#FCE3FC;
 color:#33AAFF;"
}

.ul_samp1 {
 position: absolute;
 top:256px;
 left:156px;
 background-color:#C9FFF0;
 color:#33AAFF;"
}
```

```html
<body onmousemove="move_area(event)">
<div id="area"></div>


<div class="div_samp1">div</div>
<p class="p_samp1">some example of paragraph</p>

<ul class="ul_samp1">
 <li>value 1</li>
 <li>value 2</li>
 <li>value 3</li>
</ul>

</body>
```

Comment: hmm!! This is some what similar or very close to one which now I'm writing but my concern with this solution is : It will go check every other element of HTML page as I mentioned in earlier answer's comment that my webpage consists of thousands of DOM elements (its an SVG) so using this approach raise issue on performance. So somewhere we need to optimize the way to search the  DOM objects. If you have any idea how they do with jQuery zoom plug-ins for images, I think that could help. Thanks for this effort @Pawel

Comment: does all these elements got static width, height and x and y position after page load? and does your area has got static coords every time or you want to set onmousemove for area and change X and Y pos during mouse move (as in my example)?

Comment: No elements are not static. Only thing rectangle has got static height and width for selection which also for later point of time may be changed to resizeable. And the thing for selection will be clicked based but simultaneously on the same click few other actions needs to be performed.